# Netbeans 8.2 can't edit persistence.xml

Tags: ubuntu, netbeans-8

If I navigate to "Other Sources" -> META-INF -> persistence.xml then I get a GUI which is very annoying as it does not list my hibernate, or C3P0 properties. I just want an xml editor.

To edit the xml, currently I need to right click the file then in the pop up menu: "tools" -> "open in terminal" (which opens a terminal in the right folder and type "gedit persistence.xml").

Editing this file in this way is really annoying.

When I right click the file there are two options "open" and "edit" both result in the same GUI.

All other xml files (I even tested putting one right beside persistence.xml in case the META-INF was magical, and they all would be editable as expected).

Because I can't find others with this issue, I have a feeling it might be something local. Using Ubuntu 17.04.

This is what my UI looks like:
[image]

I also right-clicked the persistence.xml file to show the dialog options but none of them open the file in a way the xml can be edited, they either open design view, history does actually show the history...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the "GUI" you see when you **Open** or **Edit** the file **persistence.xml** similar to this?...

[image: designView]

If so, then the file is (incorrectly) being opened by NetBeans in **Design** view, and all you need to do is click the **Source** tab (to the immediate right of the **Design** tab) to be able to edit the raw XML:

[image: sourceView]

As you pointed out, this problem does not impact all XML files; it seems to be only **persistence.xml** which opens in **Design** view. That's a bug, and I have raised a bug report with NetBeans:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271695

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Updated based on feedback from the OP:

- Other NetBeans users have reported a problem similar to that in the OP, where they only see the **History** view, but not the **Source** view. Presumably that was for non-XML files, so the **Design** view was not relevant.
- The solution that worked for them was to delete their User directory.
- The name of that directory is shown by selecting **About** from the **Help** menu in NetBeans.
- Close NetBeans before deleting the directory. It will be automatically recreated when NetBeans is restarted.
- See the following for full details:

https://forums.netbeans.org/topic59936.html

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=252111

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

Comment: Thank you, I don't know what the issue is but I don't have those tabs. I've added a screen shot to the question to demonstrate, and show that I'm not blind =). Since I've had the issue for a while and am using Ubuntu this might somehow be specific to that, although I don't understand how.

Comment: I've added myself the CC list for that bug report. Thank you for opening it.

Comment: @Quaternion Very strange! Perhaps try using the NetBeans Project wizard to create a throwaway Web Project, then for that project do File->New File...->Persistence->Persistence Unit to create a persistence.xml file for that project. Can you open that file in "Source" view? If so then the problem is specific to the project in your OP. Either way, also do Help->Check for Updates just in case your version of NetBeans is not up to date. I doubt if that will help, but it can't hurt.

Comment: @Quaternion Based on your feedback I have updated my answer.

Comment: excellent it is working! This has persisted for several NB versions but I without thinking kept importing the previous settings when asked to do so. This has resolved the issue.

Comment: @Quaternion Great. Just to be clear though, does persistence.xml still open in Design view rather than Source view when you select Open or Edit? (If the file is correctly opened in Source view for you then I need to update the Bug Report.)

Comment: It still opens in design view. However given that I've been doing: [right click file]->Tools->"Open in Terminal", then type "gedit persistence.xml" several hundred times... Having to click on "source" isn't bad at all... of course because of some assumptions it makes (about using EclipseLink) I would rather it try to help me as little as possible regarding this "design view"... so I guess there is an issue but the one that started this question is certainly resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have just solve this issue, here drop you the solutions, it works for me.

go to: ***view>show editor toolbar***, if non selected then select them and ready, right now i solved it.XD